# Very large fseek forward equivalent for stdin?

Tags: c, stdin, fread, fseek

I have a very large, known number of bytes on stdin, and wish to discard a large (also known) number of them before reading the portion of interest (in other words, I want to fseek forward by a large integer, but fseek isn't defined for pipes). The simplest way to achieve this seems to be a large number of calls to fgetc, and the first alternative is to use a single call to fread with a large scratch pointer allocated to store the result. The first is very slow, and the second uses a potentially unbounded amount of memory for no good reason. Making multiple smaller reads solves the unbounded memory usage issue, but introduces a free parameter (the chunk size) which probably has a different fastest value for every machine and OS combination.

Are there any alternatives that achieve this goal in a neat, efficient fashion? POSIX is assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to "skip" data on a pipe - you have to read it.

If it's a very large block, you will want to use a medium-sized buffer (as a compromise between overhead and memory usage), something like this:

```
 size_t dataToRead = some_large_number;

 while(dataToRead)
 {
    char buffer[4096];
    size_t toread = min(sizeof(buffer), dataToRead);
    size_t nread = fread(buffer, 1, toread, stdin);
    dataToRead -= nread;
 }
```

The size, 4096 is a rather arbitrary choice - but it's big enough not to cause a HUGE number of reads to the input, and small enough to not use crazy amounts of stack-space. It is unlikely that you will gain/loose much from changing this size.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Yes, I thought about that, and then got "sidetracked" making sure I got the `fread` arguments the right way around (since I always want to put the "file" as the first argument, and never can really remember which is "count" and "size" in the middle...)

Comment: I rm'ed my comment once you fixed it. No worries. It was an obvious oversight.

Comment: Your 4096 is the free parameter from my original question. Presumably there is a speed advantage due to this being the page size, or rationally related to the page size, on most architectures of interest. However, would it be faster to malloc the buffer instead of declaring stack space for it? Does the latter guarantee any sort of alignment?

Comment: It may have some advantage being page-sized, but it is not automatically aligned. It is most likely not worth calling `malloc`, as that is A LOT longer than the single instruction needed to make space on the stack, and to gain that back, you need to gain quite a lot - I doubt `fread` isn't going to be that much better.

Comment: That makes sense, although if you were going to reuse the same buffer for many such seeks of the same or less size, presumably there is a point where the single malloc() call is worth it.

Is there any speed difference between fread(buffer, 1, toread, stdin) and fread(buffer, toread, 1, stdin) ?

Another small correction to your answer: min() isn't defined for integers in C.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that somewhere `size` and `count` are multiplied together for the read anyway, so there should be no difference between `1, toread` and `toread, 1`. I see absolutely no reason why you should `malloc` the buffer - it makes no difference at all - `read` which is the underlying system call will read into a kernel buffer, which is then copied. As long as it's aligned to something like 4 or 16 bytes [which it will be automatically], there's no reason for further alighment.